# How to use Code splitting in Webpack to have custom outputs?

Tags: javascript, optimization, webpack, chunks, code-splitting

Currently I have only one bundle JS for my all app (this is bad I know...). I want to use the code splitting from Webpack to optimize it but I can't succeed to do what I have in mind.

I have my main app.js file:

```
import './components/cookie';
import './components/accordion';
import './components/sidenav';
import './components/product';
etc.
```

I want to create a new file for all component related to profile pages. So I took those import from the main app.js and put it in the new profile.js:

```
import './profile';
import './order';
import './payment';
import './address';
import './subscription';
```

Now, I would want to have 2 files in output:

1. main app.js with all its vendors included
2. profile.js that would contain only profile related JS and would load shared vendors from app.js. If any vendor related to profile.js itself, they should be included directly in this file.

For some context, the app.js would be loaded on all pages while profile.js would be loaded only on specific pages.

But currently i can only have these outputs:

```
                 Asset      Size               Chunks             Chunk Names
                app.js   225 KiB                  app  [emitted]  app
        app~profile.js   105 KiB          app~profile  [emitted]  app~profile
            profile.js   112 KiB              profile  [emitted]  profile
        vendors~app.js  34.2 KiB          vendors~app  [emitted]  vendors~app
vendors~app~profile.js   524 KiB  vendors~app~profile  [emitted]  vendors~app~profile
Entrypoint app = vendors~app~profile.js vendors~app.js app~profile.js app.js
Entrypoint profile = vendors~app~profile.js app~profile.js profile.js
```

My webpack.config is as below:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/js/app.js',
        profile: './app/js/components/profile/_all.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts/')
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
};
```

Is there any way to get the outputs that I want in the first place? Or am I not thinking in the right way for this kind of code splitting?